# Node.js 6.9.1 Express Handlebars - Can't set custom Views Path (tried the other solutions and it still won't work)

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

I am having an issue with Express Handlebars right now. I believe I have gone through the articles saying that in order for a custom view to work, i need to specify the layoutsdir correctly, which, i already did. this is the same for partialsdir. i've tried it as a string, as well, not an array, and it still doesn't work.

If you see on the console i've added in this post, you will notice that when i log them, they appear to be correct as well as for the intialization of the engine wherein it's properly populated with the right values and the views variable has been set but it still doesn't work. it will still say that the dashboard/index handlebars file isn't loaded.

**Point of entry:** /bin/dev

**Index Filename for your reference:** server/views/dashboard/index.handlebars

**app.js snippet**

```
var viewsPath = path.join(__dirname,'views');
var layoutsPath = path.join(viewsPath,'layouts');
var partialsPath = path.join(viewsPath,'partials');

app.set('views', viewsPath);

console.log(viewsPath);
console.log(layoutsPath);
console.log(partialsPath);

let exphbsConfig = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    layoutsDir: layoutsPath,
    partialsDir: [partialsPath]
});

app.engine('handlebars', exphbsConfig.engine);
app.set('view engine','handlebars');
```

**dashboard controller snippet**

```
res.render('dashboard/index', { data: grouped, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, statuses: statuses, status: status, user: req.user.email });
```

**console logs**

> E:\dino\development\src\node\app-folder\server\views
>   E:\dino\development\src\node\app-folder\server\views\layouts
>   E:\dino\development\src\node\app-folder\server\views\partials Running
>   on port 3001. Connected to mongodb on mongoURL... Error: Failed to
>   lookup view "dashboard/index" in views directory
>   "E:\dino\development\src\node\app-folder\views"
>       at EventEmitter.render (E:\dino\development\src\node\app-folder\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (E:\dino\development\src\node\app-folder\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
>       at E:/dino/development/src/node/app-folder/server/controllers/dashboardController.js:36:8
>   GET /dashboard 500 2274.734 ms - 628

[image: This is my current Tree]

Comment: Is `app.js` the main entry point of your app? If so, I think you should remove the `server` in your views path, as the current process is using a file that is already inside the server directory. --- Also, for future questions, please don't use screenshots to show code/error messages; copy and paste the relevant bits in using code snippets and blockquotes respectfully :)

Comment: I'm sorry, ImClarky. I've updated it now. I agree that this is a better approach. Should have realized this before posting. :P This code that I have right now still gives the same error. The point of entry is in bin/dev, BTW. I tried remove the custom view path as well as removethe layoutsDir and partialsDir options and it still didn't work. :(